# Rails & Backbone.js: Passing a Custom Method, Getting "UnknownAttributeError"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, backbone.js

I have some custom methods defined in my task model.  I'm sending them into my backbone application like so:

```
Planner.initialize({ tasks: #{raw @tasks.to_json(:methods => [:timeframe, :timeframe_title, :timeframe_months]) } });
```

However, after I added that, ActiveRecord thinks it's a field in the database, and I'm getting the following error in the console:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms

ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute: timeframe):
  app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb:118:in `block in update'
  app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb:117:in `update'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Chad Pytel at ThoughtBot, I found that I had to remove these three methods from my attr_accessible line in my rails model.

Highly recommend the book ["Backbone.js on Rails" by Thoughtbot](https://learn.thoughtbot.com/products/1-backbone-js-on-rails), which comes with chat support for problems like these.

Comment: Other alternatives: manually whitelist `params` in your controller, adjust your Backbone model's `toJSON` to not include those things and use a separate method for serializing your models for your Backbone view templates. You can accept your own answers too but you might need to wait another ~5 hours.